# How to make highlighted input text

Tags: javascript, html, css, input, contenteditable

I want to make colored input text, in other words, I want it to look like this:

[image: Colored]

> Not this:

[image: Not Colored]

Please show me how to do this is possible, and I'm assuming you'll use a `<div>` element with the attribute of `contenteditable`

Comment: Show us what you have tried. SO isn't a free code writing service. The objective here is for you to post your attempts to solve your own issue and others help when they don't work as expected. See [ask] and [mcve]

Comment: I've never tried it before because I don't know how to do it, that's why I'm asking.

Comment: Each of those groups of same color characters need to be in a styled span to give the characters the color. `<span class="purple">create</span><span class="red">(</span><span class="blue">"</span>....`

Comment: Yes I know that, but what if you type more, like in a div with the attribute contenteditable active, then it won't be colored unless your typing in a span element?

Comment: Not a trivial thing to do yourself in a contenteditable without a script to parse it all. Is this code? If so use a code editor script. There are a variety of those around

Answer (score 0):

Try checking out [HighlightJS](https://highlightjs.org/) it is usually being used for highlighting code snippets, it also allows you to customize the style and tags.